# MySQL Backup Cron Job

Tags: mysql, backup, cron, password

I have a cron job which backup up my MySQL database by exporting it. The script includes the root password to get the job done.

I get the message:

```
Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure
```

which is quite right, of course.

The original script is:

```
mysqldump \
    --single-transaction \
    [more options]
    --user=root \
    --password= … \
> /data/mysql/mysql.sql
```

I know that the following should work if I have this in `~/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
user = root
password = …
```

and omit the user & password in the script. However I get the following error message:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
(using password: NO) when trying to connect
```

which tells me it’s not working.

Obviously I’m doing something wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the one thing to know about cron is its like env-less. So it might not know about /root/.my.cnf

You might want to try the following flag to point to the full path to the config that stores the user/pass

```
 --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That did it, but it needs to be stressed that this option has to be placed first. See bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31312